# In If condition getting error and not going to Else condition

Tags: apex, rest-api, rest, exception

I have below code where i am chechking if recordtype is not 0 and if its blank then go to else and throw an error.but if recordtype is coming null then its trwoing **Attempt to de-reference a null object** error.Please suggest how can i handle this error.

```
try {
    Id devRecordTypeId;
    devRecordTypeId = (schema.SObjectType.case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Develpment' ).getRecordTypeId());
    if(devRecordTypeId!=null || devRecordTypeId!='' ){
        case cse=new case();
        System.debug('inside IF::');
        cse.status=obj.cse.Status;
        cse.Origin=obj.cse.Origin;
        cse.RecordTypeId=devRecordTypeId; 
        Insert cases;
        RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        RestContext.response.statusCode = 201;
        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(''succsess');
    } else {
        RestContext.response.statusCode = 400;
        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Error:Recortype error');
    }                             
} catch(Exception ex){

}
```

Comment: `schema.SObjectType.case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Develpment' )` are you sure this is not `Development` instead of `Develpment` ? If so, you are doing `null.getRecordTypeId()` leading to crash

Comment: yes even if its incorrect record type, i wanted to handle this in else and throw appropriate error message

Answer (score 2):

Possible refactor:

```
SObjectType sObjectType                        = Schema.Case.SObjectType;
Map<String, Schema.RecordTypeInfo> recordTypes = sObjectType.getRecordTypeInfosByName();

// This make you sure this record type exists (or not) without throwing exception
if(recordTypes.contains('Develpment')) {
  Id devRecordTypeId = recordTypes.get('Develpment').getRecordTypeId();
      Case cse = new Case(
      status       = obj.cse.Status;
      Origin       = obj.cse.Origin;
      RecordTypeId = devRecordTypeId; 
    );
    // cases.add(cse); Insert cases; ?? Or insert cse; 
    RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    RestContext.response.statusCode   = 201;
    RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(''success');
} else {
  RestContext.response.statusCode   = 400;
  RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Error:Recordtype does not exist');
}
```

Or

```
try {
    Id devRecordTypeId = Schema.Case.SObjectType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Develpment').getRecordTypeId();
    if(String.isNotBlank(devRecordTypeId)){
        Case cse = new Case(
          status       = obj.cse.Status;
          Origin       = obj.cse.Origin;
          RecordTypeId = devRecordTypeId; 
        );
        // cases.add(cse); Insert cases; ?? Or insert cse; 
        RestContext.response.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        RestContext.response.statusCode   = 201;
        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(''success');
    } else {
        RestContext.response.statusCode   = 400;
        RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Error:Recortype error');
    }                             
} catch(Exception ex){
  RestContext.response.statusCode   = 400;
  RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('Error:Recortype ' + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Instead of code dump also add what did you change and how it will help.

Comment: still its throwing error before if

Comment: @tarun Could you provide all the code + the entire exception ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using `OR` condition here instead use `&&` to make sure both are true.

Your current condition will always return true because a string can only be empty or null at a time.

Also you need to make sure RecordType exist so you need add null check here as well.

```
Id devRecordTypeId = schema.SObjectType.case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().ContainsKey('Develpment' ) ? schema.SObjectType.case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Develpment' ).getRecordTypeId() : '';
if(String.isNotBlank(devRecordTypeId) )
```

Comment: even if its && it thorwing error above if condition Attempt to de-reference a null object.and not error msg of else cond.

Comment: @tarun are you sure you are getting value here `schema.SObjectType.case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Develpment' )`. Check if it is not null

Comment: You can also change this line `if(devRecordTypeId!=null && devRecordTypeId!='' ){` to `if(String.isNotBlank(devRecordTypeId)) {`, gives same result and easier to read.

Comment: @ Tushar Sharma --Even if its null it needs to go to else but its thrwoing attempt to derefernce a null object error

Comment: @tarun check my updated answer. You are getting null pointer before the if condition.